PDO, execute an invalid query or a query with a syntax error and receive an error message
class bb
{

    public $con;

    function __construct() {
        $this->con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=table', 'user', 'pass', [
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'", 
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC]);
    }

    function query($sql, $value, $type = false)
    {
        $this->sql = $this->con->prepare($sql);
        if (!$this->sql) {
            print_r($this->connect->errorInfo());
            die();
        }
        $this->sql->execute($value);
        return $type ? $this->sql->fetch() : $this->sql->fetchAll();

    }
}

$bb = new bb;
print_r($bb->query("SELECT * FROM `news2` WHERE `id_f` = ?", ['269']));

I make a request, it works. I make a request for a non-existent table and the page returns a 500 code. Instead of displaying an error
if (!$this->sql) {
    print_r($this->connect->errorInfo());
    die();
}

What am I doing wrong?

Did you check your web server's error_log (or the PHP-FPM error log)? That's the first thing you do when you get a 500.

Cleared all logs, all folders. Then reloaded the page with response code 500, and then looked for logs. Strangely, no logs were created.

Often log files are only opened on service startup, not for each line, so if deleted they might not be recreated until restart – i.e. the service would keep writing to the "deleted" file. (Though it's possible that logs go to 'journalctl' instead...) Do you have an error_log defined in the web server for this vhost?
